# tesseract whole number recognition within a text block

Tags: linux, opencv, ubuntu, ocr, tesseract

I'm quite new to tesseract and also openCV. I'm building a simple Linux application to dictate printed text on paper. using tesseract I managed to do text block recognition however if there is a whole number in the text block the number will be omitted. example
Input:
"Hello this is my 3D video in 2014 that is 1080p "
Output:
"Hello this is my 3D video in that is 1080p "

Anyone have encounter this issue before?

openCV :2.4.9
Tesseract:V3.02 
Leptonica: 1.71
OS: Ubuntu 64bit 14.04 LTS

Regards

Comment: Have you reliably repeated this on other sentences with pure numbers in them? Note 3D and 1080p work, so it's not an issue with the training data I think.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't seen this before but I know you can change this kind of behaviour with the Page Seg Mode some times. Are you using Automatic page segmentation? Try some of the other settings and input the text per block, line or even word. You can change the Page Seg Mode according to the manual in the following way:

```
-psm N
Set Tesseract to only run a subset of layout analysis and assume a certain form of image. The options for N are:

0 = Orientation and script detection (OSD) only.
1 = Automatic page segmentation with OSD.
2 = Automatic page segmentation, but no OSD, or OCR.
3 = Fully automatic page segmentation, but no OSD. (Default)
4 = Assume a single column of text of variable sizes.
5 = Assume a single uniform block of vertically aligned text.
6 = Assume a single uniform block of text.
7 = Treat the image as a single text line.
8 = Treat the image as a single word.
9 = Treat the image as a single word in a circle.
10 = Treat the image as a single character.
```